# Deleting record in two table in one query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have two tables

```
EMPGROUP_TBL
SEQID | MASTERID | BUSINESS_UNIT | DIVISION | SUB_DIVISION | CLASSIFICATION | SUB_CLASSIFICATION
```

and

```
EMP_MASTERTBL
MASTERID | EMPNO | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | JOBTITLE | LOCATION |
```

In my table in ASP.NET JOBTITLE, BUSINESS_UNIT, DIVISION, SUB_DIVISION, CLASSIFICATION and SUB_CLASSIFICATION are together.

So when I have to delete the record in girdview I only need to delete the JOBTITLE in EMP_MASTERTBL and all the record in EMPGROUP_TBL.

This is my code

```
DELETE em.JOBTITLE, eg.BUSINESS_UNIT, eg.DIVISION, eg.SUB_DIVISION, eg.CLASIFFICATION, eg.SUB_CLASSIFICATION
FROM EMP_MASTERTBL AS em, EMPGROUP_TBL AS eg
WHERE em.MASTERID = eg.MASTERID AND eg.MASTERID = '76196'
```

Everytime I run or execute my code there's an error which is `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

I tried different approach for my code but it's still the same.

I also tried this

```
DELETE JOBTITLE FROM EMP_MASTERTBL WHERE MASTERID = '76196';
DELETE FROM EMPGROUP_TBL WHERE MASTERID = '76196'
```

But I got an `Invalid object name 'JOBTITLE'.` error.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You have to run two separate `delete` queries first on Master table and then on other table.

Comment: You can not delete column with delete query. You can replace value by null using Update query, Why don't you use update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you DELETE FROM a table you are not deleting from a particular field, are you are deleting the entire row. That is why when you write the delete statement you don't include field names.

It is also possible to set up a foreign key relationship between your two tables so that when you delete from   EMP_MASTERTBL it also deletes the child records in EMPGROUP_TB. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

**Edit**

On closer reading of your updated question, I think what you would really like to do is this:

```
UPDATE EMP_MASTERTBL
   SET JOBTITLE = NULL
   WHERE MASTERID = '76196';

DELETE FROM EMPGROUP_TB
   WHERE MASTERID = '76196';
```

That is, you're setting the `JOBTITLE` to NULL, and deleting all related records in `EMPGROUP_TB`.

Comment: but if I use DELETE FROM EMPGROUP_TB
  WHERE MASTERID = '76196'; will all the record in EMPGROUP_TBL be deleted? Including the LASTNAME etc.?

Comment: @chobowski The whole record including all details will be deleted.  See revised answer. If this is. It what you want then 'DELETE' is not the right action.

Comment: `You can't delete from multiple tables in a single statement` that statement **I strongly disagree with**, you most certainly can. For example an inner or left join to the tables...

Comment: @mendosi Thank you very much for your help. I got the output that I want.

Comment: @Zaggler Yes, you are correct. I have edited my answer accordingly.